# are these functions orthogonal on $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to show that the functions $1,\cos(t),\cos(2t),...$ is ortogonal on $[-\pi,\pi]$? Thank you for the hint? is this as wronkian in differential equations?

Comment: you just do the integrals. That's all. The inner product is $  \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) g(x) dx  $ multiplied by a fixed constant. When you get $0,$ then $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the inner product you have in your mind is the following: 
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)g(t)dt.$$
Then for $m\neq n$ we have 
$$\langle \cos(m t),\cos(nt)\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(m t)\cos(nt)dt
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [\cos(m t+nt)+\cos(mt-nt)]dt=...$$
I think you can finish it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make the point clearer. If we set $\phi_0(t)=1,~~\phi_n(t)=\cos(tx)$ then we must show that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi_0(t)~\phi_n(t)dt=0,~~~n\neq0$$ and $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi_m(t)~\phi_n(t)dt=0,~~~n\neq m$$ In fact, if you compute the integrals above you will get: $$(\phi_0,\phi_n)=0,~~~n\neq0$$ and $$(\phi_m,\phi_n)=0,~~~n\neq m$$